# Creating two power automate flows to overcome the 5000 row cap

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I created two power automated flows which copies rows from two different excel spreadsheets and paste them in to the same SharePoint list.

First flow copies 3999 rows and runs without any issues. The second one starts a few minutes after the first one (both flows are timed) and copies only 1014 rows and then gets stuck in apply to each.

The total always comes to 5013, is this somehow still limited by the 5000 row cap or is there another hidden cap?

Tried doing this with different excel files and SharePoint list but still getting stuck in apply to each.

Comment: You need to show your flow or something to clarify your point of issue.

Comment: Can you show us the flow you are using? You can change excel action settings to get more items from excel file and maybe use concurrency control settings for apply to each action to get more list items added quickly.